# Permutate all posibilities for N lists with M length of middle array

Tags: python, list, random, size, permutation

I'm trying to carve some files. In order to do so, I'd like to permutate all possibilites. There are 3 possible beginnings, 40 possible middle blocks and 3 possible endings.

The problem is that we don't know how long the middle block is. It could be 1 block long but also 40 blocks longs. The only thing we know for sure is that the blocks appear consecutively since it is a PNG I'm trying to recover.

I already tried hand writing the code myself with a lot of for loops, without succes so far. 
I did try the following code.

```
s= [[headersList],[idatList],[iendList]]
    print(list(itertools.product(*s)))
```

I expect the output to be something like,

```
[1, [1], 1]
[1, [1,2] , 1]
[1, [1,2,3], 1]
...
[2, [1] ,1]
[2, [1, 2], 1]
```

And so on.
The only condition is that the start and end block have to be on the corresponding beginning and ending of the array. The middle blocks have to be size 1 to max 40 in consecutive order.

Comment: Could you give a concrete example of a sample input and corresponding sample output?

Comment: Can you clarify if 1,2,7  is valid or not? I guess it is not valid. And whether it should start with 1 always? Is 3,4,5 a valid middle block_ and then you have only 40 combinations for middle, and a total of 3x40x3 = 360 permutations you are trying to generate.

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy it's a hex data file so it's quite long to post it here. It's supposed to be one PNG block, N idat blocks, and one iend block.

Comment: @EmmetB the first and last number should be between 1 and 3. Since there are 3 starting blocks and 3 ending blocks. The middle block is N long with a maximum of 40. The thing I do know is that the numbers in the middle block appear consecutively.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you should use product:

```
from itertools import product

head   = range(1,4)
tail   = range(1,4)
middle = range(1,41)
combos = [(h,list(range(1,m+1)),t) for t,h,m in product(tail,head,middle)]


print(combos)
# [(1, [1], 1), (1, [1, 2], 1), (1, [1, 2, 3], 1), 
#  (1, [1, 2, 3, 4], 1), (1, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 1), ...
```